# Is this the code the compiler generates from the following query expression?

Tags: c#, linq

```
     var result = from c1 in a1
                  from c2 in a1.a2
                  from c3 in a1.a2.a3
                  select new { c1.id, c2.id, c3.id };
```

Is this the code the compiler generates from the above query expression:

```
var result = a1.SelectMany(
      c1 => a1.a2.SelectMany(
         c2 => a1.a2.a3.Select(
            c3 => new {c1,c2,c3})));
```

thank you

Comment: It compiles these down to IL. You can use a disassembler such as Reflector to see this IL.

Comment: @Oded: but there is a conversion of sorts from query syntax to extension methods, right?  Anyway the OP asks if they are equivalent.

Comment: If you have any other doubt on which code the compiler is going to  generate use LINQPad :)

Comment: Doesn't LINQPad only convert to IL and not C#? I don't know IL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

This is a full outer join and will contain `a1.Count * a2.Count * a3.Count` items, including every combination of items from the source sequences/