# How can we express the following code using query expression?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

How can we express the following code using query expression:

```
        var result = collection1
            .Select(p1 => p1. collection2
                .Select(p2 => p2.collection3
                                       .Select(...)));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you *can* use:

```
var result = from p1 in collection1
             select p1.collection2 into p2
             select p2.collection3 into p3
             select p3....;
```

However, I suspect it's more likely that your original `Select` calls were meant to be `SelectMany`, in which case you'd get:

```
var result = from p1 in collection1
             from p2 in p1.collection2
             from p3 in p2.collection3
             select p3....;
```

It really depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: 1 - Just to be sure ... select into returns the entire result set of a »previous« query? 2 - "It really depends on what you're trying to do." I'm learning query expression syntax and thus I'm just trying to think of varius combinations of operator calls and how to express them using query expression syntax. Thus I'm not trying to do anything specific

Comment: @user702769: "select into" is like declaring a whole separate query - all the previous range expressions are out of scope; all that's left is the new one declared by the "into".

Answer (score 3):

It *looks* like what you are trying to express is really a `SelectMany`, where you have a collection that has a collection, that might have a collection, and this continues for *n* levels.

In query expression syntax, that would be

```
var result = from p1 in collection1
             from p2 in p1.collection2
             from p3 in p2.collection3
             ... // continues to n
             select pn;
```

Comment: "It looks like what you are trying to express is really a SelectMany" Heh, I already asked about SelectMany at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380194/is-this-the-code-the-compiler-generates-from-the-following-query-expression